# Web development - How to guarantee the position of some elements over a background image?

Tags: html, css, image

I have a client who has given me a image that he wants to be his background. On top of that image at a specific location he wants to have text on it, more specific that will be links. For example a picture of a building, and on the door of the building he wants some text to say door. (this is just an example, can't share the real photo, cause he is a photograph, and it is an unpublished photo).

I asked him to give me both 4:3 version, and 16:9 version of an image, so I can force it full screen and keep the original aspect without cutting the image. How can I make the text to always be at the same location no matter the screen resolution of the user or the aspect of the image. Have an idea to check the current resolution, and to load the appropriate image.

Is something like this possible? The images must not be scaled or cropped, they must remain in their original aspect.

Comment: Yes, it's very simple.  Your image would be in a div then inside of the div, you will have the container for the link which you would `position:absolute;`.  Next time asking a question, please show us what you've tried.  This is more of a "help me try" not "do for me" site

Comment: @ntgCleaner, sorry I use this site a lot. First time posting on it. I have been using background-size: cover; for the background image and margin-top, margin-left, for the element. But having problem with different resolutions, and different aspects of an image. I will try with absolute positioning. Thanks.

Comment: No problem.  If you have to switch from 4:6 to 16:9, you may want to name the classes as such.  If the image is 4:6, give the containing div a `class="image4x6"` or something like that.  Then you can `position:absolute` the link div inside of that and it will always be in the right spot

Answer (score 0):

use

```
    background-size: 100% 100%; /*keep bg image full size of div*/
    background-position:fixed /*this will keep bg position fixed*/
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8rmpn/)

To maintain aspect ration while keeping the position of bg image fixed,use :

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8rmpn/2/)